# Where is lower semicontinuity uesd in the following proof?

Tags: real-analysis

I fail to see where lower semicontinuity is used in the following proof:

[image]

Of course that the set $F_t$ is closed follows from this fact but I cannot see if this is used later in the proof. As i see it we don't need $F_t $ to be closed for: $d(x,F_t) $ to be Lipschitz, for $\mathcal {l }_{k,t } (x) $ to increase poitwise to $t\{g>t \}$, for the pointwise supremum of the functions $\mathcal {l }_{k,t } (x) $ to equal $g $, or for $\max_{j \le i } h_j $ to be Lipschitz. What have I missed?

For notation: $BL(X)$ denotes the set of bounded Lipschitz functions and $\{g>t \} $ denotes the indicator function for the set $\{x:\ g(x)>t \} $.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely is a necessary condition. Take for example, the function
$$g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x = 0 \\ 0, & \text{if } x \neq 0 \end{cases}.$$
Clearly $g$ is bounded below by a constant, but is not lower semicontinuous. Note that if $g$ is minorised by a continuous function $f : \Bbb{R}$, then $f(x) \le 0$ on a dense set, hence $f(0) \le 0$. This means that there cannot be any continuous function (let alone Lipschitz) that approximates $g$ pointwise from below.

As for where explicitly the proof uses it, I'm not entirely sure, due to the odd notation, but I greatly expect it's assumed where the proof says

> ... because $d(x, F_t) > 0$ if and only if $g(x) > t$.

When $F_t$ is not closed (as is the case for our $g$), it is possible for $g(x) > t$, but $d(x, F_t) = 0$ (in particular, when $x \in \overline{F_t} \setminus F_t$). In this case, taking $t = 1/2$, we have $d(0, F_t) = 0$, but $0 \notin F_t$.